# react-helmet not recognzing any dynamic meta properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

I'm using react to generate preview images for platforms like whatsapp and facebook. Ideally, if there is a specific url with a specific product, for example, then I would want the preview image to show the specific image for that product.

Right now, I got a general image to work. In my `index.html`, if I add the line like,

```
    <meta
      property="og:image"
      content="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1616277239237-1c50214ffa78?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1301&q=80"
    />
```

then if I paste my site url into whatsapp, the preview image will show this image.

I also have a `Page` component that looks like this,

```
import * as React from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

export default function Page({ meta, children }) {
  const { ogImage, ogDescription, ogTitle } = meta;

  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>{ogTitle}</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content={ogTitle} />
        <meta property="og:image" content={ogImage} />
        <meta property="description" content={ogDescription} />
      </Helmet>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And a specific product would have a url similar to,

```
http://<domain>.com/product/123
```

But if I paste that url into whatsapp, I will only see the image that is listed in my `index.html`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's an example of my code:

[image: lingering-fire-fz30h?]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's related to react-helmet, I had problems with this package too ... Try with [react-helmet-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet-async)

```
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';

...

return (
    <HelmetProvider>
      <Helmet defer={false}>
        <title>{ogTitle}</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content={ogTitle} />
        <meta property="og:image" content={ogImage} />
        <meta property="description" content={ogDescription} />
      </Helmet>
    </HelmetProvider>
  );
```

Comment: I can see the meta tags updated in elements in chrome devtools but when I share link to the page, I can still see the old meta tags which were added to index.html file

Comment: Sorry @knigalye, I can't help you, this post is old and I don't use react-helmet anymore...